# Software or method for moving between Thunderbolt display and laptop resolution

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, resolution

I have a 13" MBP and a 24" Thunderbolt display. I use the Thunderbolt display as my main and only screen while at my desk. The problem for me comes when I disconnect and take my laptop to a meeting or another location and now all the windows are over-sized for the laptop screen (ie. edges off the screen and windows much larger than the laptop screen).

Is there a quick method or a piece of software that will auto-resize all open windows to fit in the current display?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) or [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/).

Stay is specifically designed to combat this problem. It remembers window positions for a given display configuration, then switches between them as you switch displays. So when you disconnect your Thunderbolt display, your windows will resize to your settings for internal only.

Moom is a bit more of a general purpose window manager, it has a lot of different ways to reposition windows, but it also allows you to save sets of window positions, and you can set it to load one of those when the display arrangement matches certain rules.